Trigger Function Not Inserting All Records in data_sync_datahistory Table with application_name = 'dibpos_offline'
I'm working on a PostgreSQL trigger function to log changes to a data_sync_datahistory table whenever there's an INSERT or UPDATE operation on other tables. The trigger is set up to only log these changes when the application_name is set to 'dibpos_offline'. However, I'm encountering an issue where some records are not being inserted into the data_sync_datahistory table when multiple records are inserted into the database.
Here is my trigger function:
IF current_setting('application_name') = 'dibpos_offline' THEN     IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN         INSERT INTO data_sync_datahistory (created, modified, data, source, table_name)         VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ROW_TO_JSON(NEW), 'local', TG_TABLE_NAME);     ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN         INSERT INTO data_sync_datahistory (created, modified, data, source, table_name)         VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ROW_TO_JSON(NEW), 'local', TG_TABLE_NAME);     END IF; END IF; RETURN NEW; 

And here is the relevant part of my database configuration:
DATABASES = {     'default': {         'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', "postgres") if os.environ.get("DB_HOST", None) else os.path.join(Path.home(), 'dibpos.sqlite3'),         'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', "postgres"),         'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),         'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', ''),         'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', 5432),         'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,         'CONN_HEALTH_CHECK': True,         'OPTIONS': {             'options': '-c application_name=dibpos_offline'         },     } } 

Problem: When multiple records are inserted into the database, some of them are not being logged into the data_sync_datahistory table. The trigger function seems to be missing some records.
Questions:

Could the issue be related to the database configuration or the trigger function itself?

Are there any common pitfalls or things to check when using triggers with application_name settings?

Is there a way to ensure that all records are logged consistently?


Any advice or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!
